# AS 3.1.2 upgrades failed; now I can't start AS 3.1.2

Tags: android, android-studio

I've had [trouble upgrading](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52574059/2737933) AS 3.1.2 to 3.2. Now AS 3.1.2 won't start.

Last year, I assume during an upgrade, I wound up with two `Program Files\Android\` Android Studio folders: one is `Android Studio`, the other is `Android Studio1`. Their contents greatly vary.

[image: AS1]

For the same reason, I assume, I have two sdk folders in `Appdata\Local\Android\`: `sdk` and `sdk1`, whose contents greatly vary:

[image: sdk1a]

I guess it’s safe to say my 3.1.2 installation is shaky, but it worked fine until today.

After running System Restore, I can’t get AS to start no matter what I do:

```
Press Ctrl-Alt-Shift-A (the usual way)
Click on the usual shortcut on task bar
Start > Android Studio (link)
Start > All Programs > Android Studio > Android Studio
Click on either studio.exe or studio64.exe in Program Files\Android\Android Studio1
```

My only option in `Control Panel > Programs` is to uninstall any or all of the 3 items listed:

[image: uninstall]

The last time I was able to start AS 3.1.2, I saved my settings in case I have to uninstall and install newest version:

[image]

I don’t know what I might have done the last time I was in AS 3.1.2 (yesterday), but nothing seemed amiss when I exited.

So my question is:
(1) Should I uninstall AS 3.1.2 (and also the `sdk`; see above) and install latest stable version?
Or
(2) DON’T uninstall 3.1.2 (so as not to lose customizations); just install latest stable version?

(I’m kind of afraid if I choose (1) I'll lose all customizations and if I choose (2) I’ll wind up with Android Studio3 and jdk3.)

Comment: What do you mean with "customization"? The AndroidStudio settings are usually stored in the user directory not in the AS install dir. Therefore deleting it and re-installing AS is usually painless.

Comment: @Robert--"Customizations" ::= Custom settings. 

"Usually" painless? So... when NOT painless? I.e., can the install process (not me) screw up my settings?

I think I'll delete and reinstall. Can't work; what else can I do? And if it's safe, great.